# Cuando descargo un fichero excel por chrome me lo abre solo, ¿cómo lo quito?

Tags: javascript, django

Cómo puedo evitar que se habrá solo el excel que se acaba de descargar desde código, preferiblemente desde JS, pero también me sirve hacerlo desde django.

Comment: Pero eso es un tema del navegador y del SO del usuario.. no tiene nada que ver con lo que pasa de tu lado...

Answer (score 0):

Si en el la cabecera HTTP Content-type pones application/octet-stream el navegador no detecta el sistema de fichero ejecutando una simple descarga

```
Content-type: application/octect-stream
```